# Entity mapping to DTO

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, mapping

I want to map query result to DTO of the following JPQL:

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Id> {

    @Query("select f.game, sum(f.timeSpent) as duration from foo f  group by f.game order by duration desc")
    List<Foo> findMostPlayable();

}
```

As a result, I receive list of objects which consist of GameCatalog object and Long number:

```
0 = {Object[2]@10670} 
 0 = {GameCatalog@10675} 
 1 = {Long@10676} 8968
```

Foo.class looks like:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Foo{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "game_catalog_id", nullable = false)
    private GameCatalog game;

    private Long timeSpent;
}
```

I plan to use MapStruct to map model with DTO but I cannot do that since 'findMostPlayable' returns result in such a way above.

How I can implement mapping here?

And should I use JPA JPQL way or hibernate features like projections and so on?

Answer (score 0):

To get result of query with aggregate function,you can create your own class instead of using entity and use that.

Ex.

```
 public class MyFoo {

    private String game;
    private int duration;
    public String getGame() {
        return game;
    }
    public void setGame(String game) {
        this.game = game;
    }
    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }   
  }

@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Id> {

@Query("select new MyFoo(f.game as game, sum(f.timeSpent) as duration ) from foo f  group by f.game order by duration desc")
    List<MyFoo> findMostPlayable();

}
```